# Can I reduce Canon R8 continuous mode fps?

Tags: canon, continuous-drive

I'm looking to buy a new camera for sports photography and I need a camera that can shoot continuous JPEG at exactly 8fps. On the Canon R8, it looks like if I don't use the electronic shutter it'll shoot at 6fps, and with the electronic shutter it shoots at 40fps.

Is there an option where I can use the electronic shutter and choose to shoot at something slower than 40fps?

Comment: Alternative solution: Shoot at 40 fps, and only keep every 5th image.

Comment: For my use case, I take about 800k photos in a weekend. The 8fps and being ready to ship is extremely important.

Comment: NO off the shelf consumer camera takes *exactly* x-number of frames per second that consistently, particularly with mechanical shutter. Aperture, ISO, exposure time, lens correction settings, etc. all affect exactly how long the interval between frames will be. In real world situations, an "8 fps" camera will typically give you somewhere between 7-8 fps, with the fastest rate approaching 8 fps only if you have Av wide open, Tv shorter than flash sync, no AF, base ISO in bright enough light, no lens correction, etc.

Comment: 800k images at 8 fps is 27 hours of continuous exposure.  That almost sounds like you are effectively shooting video of some sort.  But in what I just looked online about the R8, it says "up to 40 fps".  So if exactly 8 fps is a requirement, perhaps you are not looking at the correct tool for the task?

Comment: What is the actual photographic problem you're trying to solve? Why do you think being able to shoot at exactly 8 fps will solve that problem?

Comment: @PeterM It'll be a 4-6 camera setup over the course of 10 days at sporting events. Runs 12 hours a day each day.  4ish seconds of shooting every two minutes or so. Its an odd use case but these ranges are what has worked really well. We shoot jpeg and upload same day.

Comment: @MichaelC 7-9 FPS is fine. The issue is that I need to upload them more or less immediately and there isn't time to edit or hand select images. I've been using 5Dm4 which shoots 7fps and it's been fine. I'd prefer 8 but anything in that range works. 6 is a bit low since we're looking at 5-8 at that point. 40fps is way too much.

Comment: @Citizen Can you explain your current workflow with the 5Dm4?  Given the size of the numbers you are throwing around, it would seem like you have 4 tethered cameras, and are uploading data straight from them.  Manually pulling memory cards to transfer data wouldn't be very productive.  And when I said only keep 1 in 5 images, I meant have software do that job for you, not manually selecting images.

Comment: @PeterM right now we do pull cards, organize them and upload them. We typically upload same day but we usually can't at the venue due to speeds not being fast enough.

Comment: use an intervalometer trigger or remote trigger and some kind of app or batch process to manually trigger at your custom rate.

Comment: Hi Citizen! Thanks for answering questions about your use-case, whether "exactly" 8 fps, etc. Please edit the content in your comments that explain your workflow, need for ~7-9 FPS, etc., into the question. This is good information that makes your question unique, and helps eliminate potentially useless answers. Thanks!

Comment: @dandavis [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655)

Answer (score 3):

You can set few different drive modes:

- High-speed continuous shooting +
  [Elec. 1st-curtain]: max. approx. 6.0 shots/sec.
  [Electronic]: max. approx. 40 shots/sec.
- High-speed continuous shooting
  [Elec. 1st-curtain]: max. approx. 6.0 shots/sec.
  [Electronic]: max. approx. 20 shots/sec.
- Low-speed continuous shooting
  [Elec. 1st-curtain]: max. approx. 3.0 shots/sec.
  [Electronic]: max. approx. 5.0 shots/sec.

Ref: [Canon product manual](https://cam.start.canon/en/C013/manual/html/UG-05_AF-Drive_0120.html).